# Search Bear notes using `grep` command

Tags: terminal, bash

With `grep`, I can search through the content of all the files in a directory, for an instance:

```
grep 'program' *.md
```

searches for the pattern `program` within the content of all `.md` files in the current directory.

How do I search the [Bear](http://www.bear-writer.com) notes in Terminal using the`grep` command?

Comment: do you have the `locate` command?

Comment: Please specify if you wish to search for the Bear notes files or search within the contents of the Bear notes files? For the former case you can use `find` command and for the latter you can use `grep` command.

Comment: I want to search the contents of Bear notes. @NimeshNeema

Comment: You can only search through the exported `.md` files created with Bear using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same `grep` command as mentioned in the question, to search through the contents of `.md` files exported by Bear. For instance, use

`grep pattern *.md`

to search for `pattern` in `.md` files in the current directory. You can use `-i` option to ignore case or `-n` to print line number in file.